# How to fix Minecraft being off-center?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows

I have a very annoying issue that is making my Minecraft experience, as well as any other games using LWJGL as an engine.

This is what my Minecraft looks like:

[image: Crap black bars, mouse pointer not on buttons, screen cut off woohoo!]

As you can see there are black bars there, and it also seems like the mouse doesn't line up with the buttons - as if the buttons are there in the black area but visually off.

This also occurs when the window is resized:
[image: WOOHOO MORE FREAKING ISSUES :D]

Same issues. Black bars also seem to remain here.

This occurs with other things that use LWJGL as well, such as CCEmuRedux (a ComputerCraft emulator that uses that engine).

[image: Sigh, I'm never free am I?]
[image: It's not fun :(]

Going fullscreen in MC does fix it but the issue returns when exiting from fullscreen. I have tried this already.

This is my system report: [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/HVvGq4ia)
For those that think that is too long, here is the summary: Windows 10 Insider Preview, latest version. NVidia GTX 660 SC EVGA, with the latest NVidia Windows 10 Driver. Java 8 latest version, x64.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: This is most likely a bug of Windows 10. It's still in preview version, so it means it has buggs, that should be reported back to Microsoft. [How to give feedback Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/197604/how-to-send-feedback-to-microsoft-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)

Comment: Windows 10 is currently not supported by Mojang, if you wanted to make a bug report.

Comment: Have you tried F11? that makes it completly fullscreen

Comment: @Slime_Wolf_99 this is most likely a Windows 10 graphics bug.

Issac, Windows 10 is highly unstable and is not recommended for daily use. Most programs do not yet support Windows 10, specifically Mojang. Also, LWJGL, which relies on OpenGL, is not yet compatible with W10. You might want to try using Windows 8.1 until a stable release comes out for Windows 10 (sometime next month, Lord willing).

Answer (score 1):

This bug seems to be gone in newer versions of Windows 10 Insider Preview.
I'm sure it is fixed in the 10240 build of Win10.

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated this is most likely a Windows 10 graphical bug.
Back on July 4th, Mojang released [this](https://mojang.com/2015/07/announcing-minecraft-windows-10-edition-beta/) announcement talking about a Windows 10 Edition Beta.

At the bottom of the article it states the following...

---

The “Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition” beta will be available for download in the Windows 10 Store beginning July 29.  Players who already have the PC edition of “Minecraft” will be able to download the Windows 10 beta version free.  Others can download “Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition” at a discounted price of $10 throughout the beta period.  Players who download “Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition” during the beta phase will still have the game when it comes out of beta, and receive all future updates to the game at no additional cost.

---

Hopefully this helps out a bit.

Sorry you have to wait just a little bit longer for a hopefully less buggy version of Minecraft!

Comment: Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition is a Windows-App version of Minecraft PE, the two will be made compatible at a later point. It's existence has absolutely no bearing on the performance of Java/LWJGL in Test builds of Windows 10.